# Why does my 24 volt DC servo motor run at 5 volt DC and not at 24 volt DC?

Tags: dc-motor, driver, servo, pid-controller

Why does my 24 volt DC servo motor move with 5 volt DC drawing 5 amps, but does not move with 24 volt DC?

The power supply is 24 volt DC up to 10 amps.

Datasheet are available for the [DS4S servo driver](http://www.cncdrive.com/downloads/DG4S_series_manual.pdf) and the [servo motor](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By7b56eFLvJbYzRvTlk2VWg5YTQ/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: The servo you listed is rated at 16 watts - at 5V you say it draws 5A (this is 25 watts) and it's likely the device is broken. The 24 volt servo states a no-load current of 50mA. Something is hideously wrong.

Comment: @Andyaka I will try a different servomotor of the same specs.

Comment: Is the motor loaded or unloaded? If loaded, does it run unloaded? Also please post exact part number of motor. For the 24V motor, the datasheet lists a terminal resistance of 6.8 ohms which makes the motor's drawing 5A (or even 1A) at 5V a physical impossibility (and suggests a dead servo driver)

Comment: Since trying different things did not help to improve the movement of the motor I decided to go back and check the wiring once more. I found out that the connections were correct but the wiring diagram WAS NOT!

The wiring diagram seems to be an old version or something.

I rewired everything by continuity checks and now everything is running smooth.

The motor does not make any noise, it does not show any position errors and the linear stage moves like if it was levitating!.

Also the current consumption is within the motor specs, not as before.

Great! now I will set the limit switches.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with pid-controller?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to tell us more about your 24V, 10A power supply, but if the motor is drawing 5A at 5V, then it looks like it'll try to draw more than 10A at 24V. It may be causing the 24V supply to shut down. You must measure the voltage at the output of the 24V supply, while you connect the motor. If the voltage drops to zero, or near zero, then the power supply is shutting down due to overload.

You may need a bigger 24V power supply.

Comment: I could not find the exact type but the PSU is similar to this one [24V power supply](http://www.applegate.co.uk/b2b-products-services/rs-components-ltd/linear-filter-psu-24vdc/470%2024-4482.html).

Comment: The Power supply does not shut down at any time. The servo drive output to the motor delivers only 270 mV.

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone and thank you for your inputs.

After trying different things I decided to remove the active current limiter value of 10 amps I had on the servodrive, I left the value to the highest possible for the servodrive of 35 amps, I do not know how much current is the servomotor drawing but now the servo is moving and I´m able to carryout out the PID tuning with consistent results.